# guess number wrongly with a %50 chance

Tags: c

In my homework user selects a number between 1 and 20 but at a chance of %50 computer can hepls wrongly.For example selected number:15 user guess:10 computer may say(guess lower number) with a %50 chance. I tried to create a chance by using another random but it selects a constant number so program always say guess higher or lower.Am I thinking wrongly ? Please help me to solve this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));                      
    int randomNum = (rand() % 20) + 1;
    int c = (rand() % 20) + 1;
    int i = 1;
    int userGuess = 0;                      
    printf("Guess a number between 1 to 20 \n"); //start with guess
    scanf(" %d", &userGuess);

    while (randomNum != userGuess) {
        if (userGuess > randomNum && c % 2 == 0) {
            printf("Guess lower number \n");    
            scanf(" %d", &userGuess);   
        } else
        if (userGuess > randomNum && c % 2 != 0) {
            printf("Guess higher number \n");
            scanf("%d", &userGuess);
        } else
        if (userGuess < randomNum && c % 2 == 0) {
            printf("Guess higher number \n");
            scanf(" %d", &userGuess);   
        } else
        if (userGuess < randomNum && c % 2 != 0) {
            printf("Guess lower \n");
            scanf("%d", &userGuess);
        }
        i++;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Post a minimal complete compilable example.

Comment: I'm sorry it's my first time in stacoverflow I forgot to add include and return thanks for the warning

Comment: Re-indenting your code shows some part is missing.  You probably forgot a closing `}` before the `return 0;`.  Avoid posting TAB characters... actually avoid **using** TAB characters as they expand differently in different environments.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a new random number `c` for the 50% condition each loop.

Move the line like `int c= (rand()%20)+1;` into the loop so that it gets a fresh number each time.

But you don't need to do the %20 or +1 on c. You are doing % 2 in the if() statement. Don't add 1 since you are already comparing it to 0 or != 0. So something like:

```
while (randomNum!=userGuess)    
{
    int c = rand();

    if(userGuess>randomNum && c%2 == 0)

...
```

Comment: thank you so much it's working :)

Comment: `rand()%2` does not necessarily provide a distribution as *random* as `rand() >= RAND_MAX/2`.

Comment: @chqrlie I totally agree. I almost added a disclaimer about the use of rand(), %, etc. But this is just a toy. To the readers, in **real production code**: Never use modulus to produce a uniform distribution. Never use rand() either. Good pseudo-random generation is hard.

Comment: @JJOJJ You can accept this as an answer if it solved the problem.